# Magento export products to csv gets stuck

Tags: php, magento, csv, export

Alright, so when I want to export my products into a csv, my page loads, and then shows this:
[image]

And it gets stuck on this page...

The part I want to export are the products with the attribute as Default, this is default because of a data Import bug that Magento has/had.
We have around 1400 products in default...

Is there any code I need to change? And if so, what is the directory to that code. I'm not an expert in Magento

Thanks you! Please go ahead and ask for more information.

Comment: so have you made sure that you have appropriate file permissions to write the data to files.

Comment: yes because it works with less products, the biggest stack of products tyhat i have succesfully exported is 150.